# Воспроизведение потокового аудио

Tags: jquery, flash, html5

Ребята, кто знает какой-нибудь плеер для сайта (jQuery, HTML5 желательно) для того, чтобы воспроизводить потоковое аудио. Аудио идет [тут](http://host.fm:7777/18742_default).

Вот собственно сам сайт: http://t.inferusvv.ru/. На данный момент там подключен jPlayer. Но он не совсем устраивает. Во первых сейчас работает только в хроме (в ФФ и Опере беда). Может я не так сделал (все видно в исходниках страницы)? Ну и второе, не очень важное, это то, что плеер при нажатии ставит аудио на паузу и потом воспроизводится с того места, где нажал паузу, а не подстраивается под эфир..

Comment: по поводу паузы - замените кнопку паузы на stop/start play

Comment: Да, я тоже почитав документацию, понял, что нужно сделать так. А оперой и ФФ разобрался. Создал второй поток в формате OGG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Побробуйте [Uppod](http://uppod.ru/). Сам не использовал, но коллеги отзывались о нём очень не плохо.

P.S. Хотел добавить, что делал краткий обзор и что порадовало: кроссбраузерность (автоматическое переключение с HTML5 на Flash, для браузеров, которые HTML5 не поддерживают), JavaScript API (управление плеером), конструктор (настройка интерфейса плеера)